# Update using Spring data JPA

Tags: spring, sql-update, spring-data-jpa

I am working on updating DB using Spring data JPA. I have update two tables simultaneously.
I was thinking about writing a query based on criteria and update but not sure how I would jot it down. Is there a better way to do it ? if so any tutorial link for that will be helpful.

Comment: Why? Just save your objects... Why would you need to write queries for that? You are using JPA then use it instead of working around it.

Comment: +1 to M. Deinum: you open a transaction, get your entities from the database, change their state, and commit the transaction. JPA will detect the changes and save them in the database. That's the basic principle of JPA.